# Is there a word for the person who hides truth in order to deceive?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say I caused a minor car crash some time ago and today I meet a woman. The conversation goes:

> Woman: Hey, I remember that car with the scratch from the crash last
>   week, you must be the one who caused it.
>
> Me: Are you sure? It didn't
>   necessarily have to be me, I see a car with a scratch like this almost every
>   day.

What I was referring to was that I see the car every day when I drive it.

Is there a word for this?

Comment: "The best lie is the truth told unconvincingly". I've seen it attributed to several people, including Mark Twain and George Danker.

Comment: "I always tell the truth, even when I lie" -Scarface

Comment: What you're doing is typically characterized as _dissembling_.

Comment: Subterfuge seems like it fits here.

Comment: @JohnC, see Sir Humphrey Appleby for excellent examples! ;)

Comment: Reminds me of a story where someone was calling to get unbiased information about "Frank" and unwittingly ended up speaking to "Frank" himself... "Do you know Frank?" "Yes I know him extremely well"... "Does Frank show up on time?"  "Well to tell you the truth I myself don't always show up exactly on time, but I can tell you one thing: whenever I'm there, Frank is there!"

Comment: ***LIAR!!!!1***

Comment: Is there something you want to tell us, Aaron?

Comment: I think it's called a Vulcan Lie (from Star Trek) where you reveal enough truth to lead the other person to draw an incorrect conclusion. Not posting it as an answer though as I can't find a citation for it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I never lie. I do, however, occasionally **deceive**. For example if someone asks me something I don't want to tell them, saying "I don't know" is a lie. Saying "I'm not allowed to tell you" may reveal the information, or encourage them to try harder to get it out of me. But "oh, I really couldn't say" or "yeah, nothing's been announced yet" often cause people to believe that I don't know, even though they are technically not lies.

Comment: What you are doing is _dissembling_.

Comment: I think deceive is more appropriate. Even if it isn't, deception is a more established word, and it doesn't break immersion in the sentence for people who have never heard of dissembling. The flow is better, in my opinion. Unless the sentence is meant to seem a tad snooty, then dissembling would be spot on.

Comment: For me, _deceive_ is to broad to be an answer - it includes all manner of deception, including simple lying.

Comment: @EdStaub Yes, I agree to some extent. I also think that "deception" is the end result of the behaviour described in the question rather than the question itself.

Comment: The request is a word for telling the truth in order to misguide. "Deceive" misses the telling the truth part.

Comment: I don't like this answer much, because when you lie you are *also* deceiving.  So it lacks the specific connotation that something like **equivocate** captures.

Answer (score 61):

To [*equivocate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocate) is to phrase your statement in an ambiguous way so that the listener is intentionally misled.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_of_mental_reservation

Comment: If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist. I rewrote my answer in my own words and changed the link which had gone bad anyway.

Comment: @Doug Great! Thanks so much, have an upvote.  Dead links are forever a problem.

Answer (score 51):

I will offer the term ***disingenuous***, which is defined [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disingenuous) as:

> lacking in frankness, candor, or sincerity

Comment: +1. Disingenuous seems more applicable here, as the "lie" (for lack of a better term) seems more dishonest in the OP's example than I'd normally associate with words like "misleading".

Comment: +1 - I think a number of the other suggestions are worthy, but `disingenuous` strikes the best tone. Not lieing, but deliberately trying not to enlighten someone.

Answer (score 50):

Prosaically, you are being:

> **misleading**

that is, saying no false hood but leading away from the truth that the other is searching for.

Comment: IMHO, this is the best answer to the specifics of the question. Others have given various synonyms for "lie", but this is the only one that really conveys the idea of telling the truth in a way intended to give the listener a false impression.

Answer (score 20):

The word *obfuscate* may apply here.

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Comment: Obfuscate, to me, means to hide the truth among a load of complexity or jargon.

Comment: -1 OP might not need a word that is making things "obscure, unclear, or unintelligible", on the contrary, judging from the example, he is looking for seemingly clear statement that will deceive someone and in such case this nice word is not really appropriate.

Answer (score 16):

I would use the word ***[prevaricate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prevaricate)***:

> *to speak falsely or misleadingly; deliberately misstate or create an incorrect impression; lie.*

Another commonly used word for this same behavior is *to fudge*, meaning to disingenuously avoid or talk around an issue.

Comment: -1 because the OP asked for a word that would mean telling the truth, yet misdirecting away from the truth.  Prevarication is a lie.

Comment: It *can* mean to lie. It can also mean *to deliberately create an incorrect impression.* (I might note that the top-rated answer, deceive, almost always means to lie; prevaricate often doesn't.)

Answer (score 13):

Your example is an instance of a *[half-truth](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/half-truth)*. Everything he said is true, but he did not tell the whole story.

Comment: A half-truth only gives part of the truth though, from the other comments I think Aaron is looking specifically for telling the _full truth_ while knowing that it will be misinterpreted. On the other hand, you can argue that the full truth would be to say that you were indeed that person. Hm.

Comment: Aaron isn't telling the *full truth*. He's deliberately suppressing facts, yet everything he *does* say is true.

Answer (score 11):

Not a single word, but the closest idiom I could find is:

> economical with the truth

Per Wikipedia:

> Economical with the truth is popularly used as a euphemism for *deceitful*, whether by volunteering false information (i.e., lying) or by deliberately holding back relevant facts. More literally, it describes a careful use of facts so as not to reveal too much information.

I would argue that outright lying is not covered by the phrase. Sir Robert Armstrong famously used the phrase during the Spycatcher trial, claiming that he had not lied -- merely been economical with the truth.

Answer (score 9):

He's using a red herring!

Source:  [this web page](http://www.nizkor.org/features/fallacies/red-herring.html) says:

> A Red Herring is a fallacy in which an irrelevant topic is presented in order to     divert attention from the original issue. The basic idea is to "win" an argument    by leading attention away from the argument and to another topic.

In your question, the original topic is about whether one of the characters (`Me`) caused a car accident.  That person then starts talking something irrelevant -- observations that he/she has made about cars in the past, thus diverting attention from the real question.

Comment: The downvote wasn't from me, but a) this doesn't answer the question, b) I'm not sure if she is employing a red herring, and c) you don't give any explanation why.

Comment: The downvote tooltip is "This answer is not useful" and explanations definitely help. A link to a source is also helpful, as is a explanation of why you think so e.g. maybe you have some insight into some usage of red herring in this case that I or the downvoter hasn't thought of or don't know about. (Also, this answer showed up as an "automatically detected low quality post" on the [review tab](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=30&filter=day) that might need some help.)

Comment: in that hypothetical example he gave.. Where he wrote "woman:" that's the woman speaking. The misguiding is what he says. So if anything is a red herring, it'd be what he said.

Comment: While a red herring can be used to mislead, it doesn't fit the example. A red herring would be something more like replying, "Oh, you were in that crash last week? Do you have insurance?" A red herring isn't a lie; it's an irrelevant side issue.

Comment: Correct, which is exactly the point I'm making: an irrelevant, but true, side issue in order to misguide.

Answer (score 6):

There's the moral concept of a" **lie by omission**". For example, if asked "Did you eat the last cookie out of the jar?" and answer "No" because you palmed it and plan to eat it later, it's technically truthful, but a lie by omission of the detail that you did palm the last cookie even though you didn't yet eat it.

Answer (score 4):

If the example is crucial to the word you are looking for, let's examine it a bit more closely

> A: Hey, I remember that car with the scratch from the crash last week, you must be the one who caused it.
>
> B: Are you sure? It didn't necessarily have to be me, I see a car with a scratch like this almost every day.

So, the crucial point is that 'a car' is used by B to mean 'some car'. However 'some car' in this context, as an argument that helps the statement that "it didn't have to be B" can only mean "a car that is not B's car". Therefore this is not just a deceit, I would still call this a **lie** (alternatively, it is a contradiction).

There are many definitions of a **lie**, I don't object to the one given by wikipedia

> A lie (also called prevarication, falsehood) is a type of deception in the form of an untruthful statement, especially with the *intention to deceive others*.

Untruthful is defined as '*not honest or true*' in macmillan.

Combining these two definitions it really is not crucial in the given example if the statement can be interpreted by someone as correct representation of reality; what is important is that the statement is not honest and has an intention to deceive. (However, I tried to show in the opening paragraph that the argument can not even be taken as something based on truth).

Wikipedia entry on deceit has the following categories:

- *Lies*: making up information or giving information that is the opposite or very different from the truth.
- *Equivocations*: making an indirect, ambiguous, or contradictory statement.
- *Concealment*: omitting information that is important or relevant to the given context, or engaging in behavior that helps hide relevant information.
- *Exaggeration*: overstatement or stretching the truth to a degree.
- *Understatement*: minimization or downplaying aspects of the truth

Under this classification you can say that it is *equivocation* ('a car' is taken to mean 'some car other than mine' and 'my car' at the same time), *concealment* (the fact that this 'some car' is actually mine is hidden) and understatement (to refer to 'my car' as 'some car' is an understatement). Finally, even under this classification you can call it a lie ('a car' is made up, it is actually 'my car' and saying 'a car was stolen' or 'my car was stolen' is very different).

Comment: Yup, I think you covered all the bases there!

Answer (score 3):

I think the second definition give for the word [casuistry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/casuistry) is dead on:

> reasoning that is specious, misleading, or oversubtle

Comment: The only place I've ever heard this word was the (excellent) book "Proofiness," where the author used it to coin a new, equally confusing-sounding term, "causistry."

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to describe your behaviour is to say you are being ***evasive***.
[Google defines](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=evasive&tbs=dfn:1) *evasive* as:

> Tending to avoid commitment or self-revelation, esp. by responding only indirectly
>    ‒  she was evasive about her phone number

This definition seems to aptly describe your situation.

It is also a behaviour seen commonly in politicians when asked a direct question!

Answer (score 3):

I must chime in with **sophistry**.  Sophists can both tell the truth and deceive at the same time; and sophistry is a good word for the overall tendency.

Answer (score 2):

President Bill Clinton coined a new expression regarding questions about himself and "that woman, Monica Lewinsky," for this context. Slightly edited, it is: "Legally accurate but not volunteering information."

Comment: What was that new expression he coined?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: What he actually said was, "While my responses were LEGALLY ACCURATE, I did NOT VOLUNTEER INFORMATION." Yours truly shortened it for personal use.

Comment: I've heard the term "Clintonian" used to mean exactly this - true, but misleading, but I didn't figure I wanted to wade into a political discussion.

Comment: We had this come up in another recent Q. The term is "parsing words".

Comment: Uh, I remember him saying “I did not have sexual relations with that woman”. That is not “legally accurate”. It’s a straight lie.

Answer (score 2):

I have also heard the term "Elfish lie", coming from the tales of nature spirits who are unable to lie, but are masters at revealing facts in a misleading way.

Answer (score 1):

I think *paradoxical diversion* best describes what you're looking for.

Comment: It can be constructed in a way that plays with the semantics and ambiguity, so as to technically not be considered a lie.

Comment: I'm not familiar with *paradoxical diversion*; what does it mean and how does it apply to this case?

Comment: Look it up in wiki, I've used the term "Paradoja Judicial" in legal motions, written in Spanish, do describe a Defendant who intentionally makes misleading affirmations in order to detour away from a topic. Its a diversionary tactic or ploy.. It's like a "Red Herring"

Comment: The term does not appear in English Wikipedia as of this date: not as a page, not even as a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Several directly-useful terms already have been suggested, such as derivatives of  *[evade](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evade#Verb)* (in its “to avoid by dexterity, subterfuge, address, or ingenuity” sense),  *[deceive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deceive#Verb)* (“To trick or mislead”), and  *[mislead](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mislead#Verb)* (“To lead astray, in a false direction”,  “To deceive by telling lies or otherwise giving a false impression” or  “To accidentally or intentionally confuse”).  I will mention several more verbs that apply:

• *[tergiversate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tergiversate#Verb)*, “To evade, to equivocate using subterfuge; to obfuscate in a deliberate manner.”
• *[waffle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waffle#Verb_2)*, “To speak or write vaguely and evasively.”
• *[palter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palter#Verb)*, “To talk insincerely; to prevaricate or equivocate in speech or actions.”
• *[diddle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diddle#Verb)*, in the sense “to cheat; to swindle” rather than a sense like *to have sex with* or *to waste time*.
• *[weasel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weasel#Verb)*, “To engage in clever or devious behavior.”

The following adjectives also are relevant:
• *[slippery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slippery#Adjective)*, “Evasive; difficult to pin down.”
• *[cagey](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cagey#Adjective)*, “uncommunicative; unwilling or hesitant to give information.”

Sources: Wiktionary entries

Answer (score 0):

She **implied** or **insinuated**. Though one can imply truthful things, insinuate has a more disingenuous tone.

e.g.

If you had your accountant fill in your tax return, someone could say:

"You didn't fill in your tax returns"

Which is true, it is a fact. You didn't, your accountant did. But the statement implies your tax returns aren't filled in, which is untrue, and as such the truthful statement implies a mistruth.

Comment: No. Implying and insinuating both involve conveying something without outright saying it. The questioner wants a word for avoiding conveying a fact, without telling an untruth (and without refusing to discuss the topic).

Comment: No, the questioner wants "A word for telling the truth (technically) in order to misguide?". I can thus declare a truthful statement, that implies something that is misguiding, while still being literally true.

e.g. "You didn't fill in your tax returns" implies your tax returns aren't filled in, which is misleading because your hypothetical accountant filled them in for you, yet the original statement is a fact, and the truth, albeit misleading.

Answer (score -2):

For fans of Pirates of the Caribbean, *Pull an [Angelica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angelica_%28Pirates_of_the_Caribbean%29)*.  She lied to Captain Jack Sparrow by telling the truth.

Answer (score -2):

A common tactic for telling the truth while intentionally misleading is by using the phrase: "What if I told you..." and variations of this. You can follow that sentence with a blatant lie and, due to technicalities, you can say anything without it being an actual lie.

Below is an example of a lie a history teacher once used to pass his interview:

> Interviewer: You seem very personable and all but how much do you actually know about Canada's history? Tell me about John A. MacDonald.
>
> Teacher: Well, I could tell you what your average Canadian knows about how John was Canada's first Prime Minister, how he secured the British North American Act, or how got his hands dirty in the Pacific Scandal and lost his office, but *what if I told you* that Mr. MacDonald was a rampant alcoholic who preferred his female companions to be between the ages of 11 and 13? What would you say then?
>
> Interviewer: Well, Mr. McGregor, clearly you know even more than I do about our history.

McGregor referred to what he did as intentionally **misguiding** but he insisted that this was in no way a lie as he technically didn't say anything untruthful.

Answer (score -2):

You're leading someone to believe in something indirectly. This reminds me of politics. **[Demagogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demagogy)** may be the answer.

Answer (score -3):

A more colorful term is a *white lie* which is a partial truth that hides a much more serious or disturbing one. The recognized definition is that this is a lie of very little consequence told with good intentions in order to cover up a larger truth that might be hurtful.

Comment: As above. And I am looking for a truth told with bad intentions.

Comment: I may have committed an SE solecism by posting two very different answers in one. So commenting on each one...'misleading' (to me) is pretty obviously a misdirection to hide something bad, i.e. not telling a falsehood but then not really answering the question.

Comment: As to 'white lie' on-line references define it as a 'small lie' not a huge falsehood, but a small lie to hide the worse truth. However, my personal reading of it has always been as I stated, saying -something- to sidestep a question to avoid having to say something bad.

Comment: @Mitch: If your personal reading conflicts with every reference and every other person's interpretation, perhaps it's time to revise it. :-) And even you say that a white lie is told to "avoid having to say something bad", i.e., is told with good intentions. What the question wants is something that could by analogy be called a "black truth".

Comment: Here is an example of what I consider a 'white lie': 'Don't worry Gramma, you'll be out of the hospital soon.'

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: understood. I'm sure there's a relevant Dilbert comic. But anyway, I don't say a 'white lie' is told with only good or only bad intentions (that is Jasper's (and the on-line) view). Anyway, anyway, 'misleading' -does- have more of the connotation of 'with negative intentions'.

Comment: -1. White lies are not told to hide "more serious or disturbing" truths, not in the sense that your phrasing would apply. They are normally told in order to hide truths that are socially awkward and unpleasant.

I would have left it at +0, but you seem to be completely unwilling to fix your answer to match actual common usage.

Comment: I agree with the downvotes. A white lie is, unambiguously, a lie.

Comment: A white lie is a "good" lie. "No, don't worry, it looks fine" or "I'm sure no-one will notice" or "no offense taken!" or "I'll treasure it always, thank you so much." You are saying something you don't believe, and in some cases don't really expect anyone else to believe, not for your own selfish reasons (a black lie) but to make the other person happier. They are not telling one kind of truth to hide another, they are just lying, but for unselfish reasons.

Comment: @Kate: The great wealth of evidence to the contrary of my opinion is slightly wafting me towards reconsideration. Or I could wish the world more in the direction of where my definition is correct. Either way, I get it. But rather than delete, I'll let it stand so people can see a _wrong_ answer.

Comment: @Mitch :-)  ... wait for one more downvote before deleting, that way you can get a badge for it :-)