# Word Request - Implying a False Truth

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for implying something that is actually false to be true, without specifically stating it to be true or false?

As an example (can’t really think of anything better):

> persons A and B on the phone:
>
> (A) Are you ready, I’m near your house.
>
> (B) (While still in bed) What do  you think, I’ll see you in 10.
>
> (A) Alright, Just checking, I’ll see  you in 10 then.
>
> (B) (Frantically tries to get ready).

Edit:
I’m gonna anwser my own question here in case someone finds this post, but I think the anwser I was looking for is:

equivocate;
“use ambiguous language so as to conceal the truth or avoid committing oneself.”

Comment: Note that 'dissembling', perhaps the best answer, is only mentioned in passing. Another, perhaps closer match is [Is there a word for the person who hides truth in order to deceive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48227/is-there-a-word-for-the-person-who-hides-truth-in-order-to-deceive/48243#48243), where 'disingenuous' is offered.